# Xcode iPhone device plays different version from iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I created an iPhone 6 class and iPhone 5 class. In app delegate I used the following code for each size to be recognized...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 CGSize iosScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if (iosScreenSize.height ==568) {

    UIStoryboard *iPhone5 =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone5" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *initialViewController =[iPhone5 instantiateInitialViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}




    if (iosScreenSize.height == 667) {

        UIStoryboard *iPhone6 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone6" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *initialViewController =[iPhone6 instantiateInitialViewController];

        self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

     return YES;
    }
```

The simulator picks up iPhone 5 storyboard when needed and iPhone 6 storyboard when needed however, the device picks the wrong storyboard. When I use the iPhone 6 device, Xcode plays my iPhone 5 storyboard on iPhone 6 device. How do I get Xcode to play my iPhone 6 storyboard on iPhone 6 device?

Comment: did u try to debug ?

Comment: Really, don't do this anyway.  Use a single, adaptive storyboard.

Comment: How do I do that? How does a single storyboard work for all different sizes for iPhone/iPad. You mean Auto Layout? Or can a single adaptive storyboard be done without Auto Layout?

Comment: You should also be aware that this code is *horrible*. Repeating multiple lines of code is a sure sign that you're doing something wrong. You should also be using `if-else` statements so that there can be a default 'fallback' option. Also hard-coding in constants like the screen height of a particular iPhone isn't that great.

Comment: Originaluser2, if else statements don't work either for my particular issue.

Comment: @HELLO I'm not saying they'll solve the problem, I'm just pointing out good habits to get into. You should be going down the path that [Paulw11 suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279340/xcode-iphone-device-plays-different-version-from-iphone-simulator#comment58270830_35279340) in creating a single adaptive storyboard.

Comment: I don't know what a single adaptive storyboard is and how to create it. Does it require auto layout? Or can it be done without Auto Layout?

Comment: In computer science, the answer is always yes. You can turn on every pixel on the screen by hand if you want to. Follow the advice above, use Autolayout, it will work on every device for the foreseeable future.

Comment: I get it use auto layout but that still doesn't explain why my above code works for all phone versions of simulators but not devices.

Comment: Have you logged the contents of `iosScreenSize.height` on the device?

Comment: jcaron47, what do you mean by logging contents of iosScreenSize.height on device?

Comment: @originaluser2 isn't being very nice, but he's right. Auto layout is the best way to do this. There are lots of tutorials you can find with a search. Here's one: http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Comment: @DaveBatton I'm sorry if you or OP feel this way, it was certainly never my intention. Re-reading through what I said, I don't see anything particularly unpleasant. I am aware that spending long periods of time on SO can make me a little too blunt, but I honestly don't think that's too bad a thing in a programming community. Quickly and concisely pointing out the bad practices of the OP's code is definitely helpful for the OP.

Comment: @jcaron47 means have you used NSLog or set a breakpoint to see what value you are getting for iosScreensize.height to try and work out why you are getting the wrong storyboard. I know you say you don't want to use autolayout but this approach is fragile. What happens when Apple releases a new device with a different screen size?  Also, what is your launch screen storyboard or image? Is it set to indicate that you support iphone6?

Comment: @Paulw11 How do I set a launch screen to indicate a specific storyboard?

Comment: You don't, but if you don't use a launch storyboard or an appropriately sized launch image your app will run in iphone5 resolution on an iphone6

Comment: @Paulw11 I use Xcode 7.2, so when I open new project Launch screen storyboard is already set up.

Comment: Ok,  I was just checking. You still haven't answered the question as to what debugging you have done on the actual device.  What height is being reported and seriously, one last time.  Use AutoLayout!!!!!

Comment: I don't know how to use the debugging tool. Never used it. I already have ann in app store. I used what I use now and everything worked well this is why it's all confusing now why it stopped working.  I've tried using Auto layout but don't like it.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger.  You can step through your code and see what it is doing.  If you can't use a tool like that or at least add some log statements it is going to be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: I did use NSLog statement but when iPhone 6 device builds and runs, the debug area, uses my iPhone 5 code

Comment: Can this issue have something to do with in Xcode's GENERAL settings under Apps Icons and Launch Images, next to Launch Image source it's automatically uses Use Asset Catalog? In my previous app it was Launch Image. But with Xcode 7.2, I can't put Launch Image there anymore.